# The out-flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(-sin(2x)+ye^(3z),-(y+1)^2,2z(y+cos(2x)+3)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, vector-fields, surface-integrals

The out-flux of the vector field
$F(x,y,z)=(-sin(2x)+ye^(3z),-(y+1)^2,2z(y+cos(2x)+3)$
from the domain $D = \{(x, y,z) \in \mathbb R^3\colon\ x^2+y^2+z^2≤4,x≤0,y≤0,z ≥ 0\}$.
is equal to

$(A)16π/
3\quad\
(B) -16π/3
\quad\
(C) -π/8\quad\
(D) π/8$

Picture of actual question is [Picture of Real Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMKCC.png)

Correct answer is 'A' but I am unable to get it.
I have tried calculating the surface integral as well as using the divergence theorem. The calculations are difficult to be shown here as I am not acquainted with the Math Latex. Please help me solve the question

Answer (score 2):

Given the *vector field* $\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ of law:

$$
\mathbf{F}(x,\,y,\,z) := \left(-\sin(2x) + y\,e^{3z}, \; -(y+1)^2, \; 2z\left(y+\cos(2x)+3\right)\right)
$$

and the *domain*:

$$
\Omega := \left\{ (x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2\le2^2, \; x \le 0, \; y \le 0, \; z \ge 0 \right\},
$$

by the **divergence theorem**, the *outgoing flow* of $\mathbf{F}$ from the boundary $\partial\Omega$ of $\Omega$ is calculated as:

$$
\Phi_{\partial\Omega}(\mathbf{F}) = \iiint\limits_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}\,\text{d}\omega = \iiint\limits_{\Omega} 4\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z = 4 \cdot ||\Omega|| = 4 \cdot \frac{\frac{4}{3}\,\pi\,2^3}{8} = \frac{16}{3}\pi\,,
$$

i.e. it's equal to four times the volume of an eighth of a ball of radius two.